# Excel not handling unload of Userform correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I unfortunately can't share the workbook that this is happening in due to security reasons. But I was wondering if anyone had experienced the following and if so how they had fixed it.

I'm having an issue where I unload one of the userforms in my workbook using

```
Unload UserForm
```

Whilst this userform is open it also changes the `Activesheet`. After the code has finished running it seems that the `Activesheet` although visually has changed for all other purposes it is still set to the previous one.

I am then unable to scroll (unless I double click into a cell first) and the whole sheet tells me it is locked (until I somehow trigger the Change procedure or manually toggle between another sheet and back).

I've also tried to `Unprotect` the sheet but in doing so the Ribbon continues on saying `Unprotect sheet` but oddly the sheet which was active when I loaded the userform becomes unprotected instead.

The Userform is loaded by using `UserForm.Show`. I haven't experienced this behaviour in any other workbooks that I have.

Have tried:

- Toggling `EnablingEvents`
- Toggling `ScreenUpdating`
- Resetting the freeze panes area
- Changing where the destination sheet is activated

All to no avail. Has anyone come across similar or know of a reason this behaviour could be experienced?

***Edit:***

Load procedure:

```
Sub SearchRev_Button()
    If ConnectToDB() = True Then
        Review_Search.Show
        Call CloseConnections
    End If
End Sub
```

Unload procedure:

```
Private Sub LoadReviewButton_Click()

    'Loads the selected review to be edited

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    If Me.ResultListBox.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case rs.Fields("ReviewMethod").Value
        Case "Review"
        If rs.Fields("ReviewMethod").Value = "ChangeReview" Then Review_ChangeReviewType.Show

        FetchReviewDetail ReviewID
        Unload Me ' <-- This is the line that unloads the userform to return to sheet
        Case "ISP"
        Unload Me
        ISP_Dash.Show

        Case Else
        MsgBox prompt:="You cannot make changes to this review", Title:=TitleString
    End Select

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Noone wants you to share a workbook (especially with vba code inside). However, you may share a bit more of the code. In general, write `End` after the `Unload UserForm` line and see whether it has "fixed" the bugs.

Comment: @Vityata There isn't really any other code to it is the issue. Tried adding `End` after `Unload` still same issue

Comment: Can you try debugging it? see if which part it executes on certain actions?

Comment: Firstly, I agree with @Vityata. But more importantly, I'm struggling to understand the issue (which is where a snippet of your code might help). Are you saying that while your form is open you update `Activesheet` but when you unload the form, you are unable to interact with your sheet? Also not sure what you meant by: **`although visually has changed for all other purposes it is still set to the previous one`**?

Comment: @ramedju Have updated with the load and unload procedures. Have debugged it many times - It all executes correctly.

Comment: @Zac whilst the userform is open I change the `Activesheet` to another one. When I unload the userform the correct sheet is displayed but any action that I do to that sheet it is like I'm doing it on the previous sheet. If I try to unprotect it the previous sheet gets unprotected and not the active one. I also can't scroll on the sheet and any `cell.Locked` settings are taken from the previous sheet as well

Comment: I assume that you are performing some form of copy from your `Previous sheet` to your `Activesheet`? if that's the case, we need to see the code unfortunately. It would be very difficult (if not almost impossible) to figure out what's going on without knowing what the code is doing. I suspect it's some action in your code that might be the root cause

Comment: @Tom Yes, I have experience the same. I will post a code that will replicate it although I have not found the solution yet too. Let me just check if I can replicate it this time using Excel 2016

Comment: @Zac There's no copy. There is a sql connection which populates the sheet.

Comment: @L42 Brilliant thank you - so do you know what causes it then?

Comment: @Tom Actually, not yet, I am trying to replicate it using minimal code, but can't seem to do it. But basically, `Unload` statement is executed after retrieving data from a database and dumped in the Excel sheet activated. The sheet is activated but you cannot scroll. You cannot edit it as well not until you select another sheet and then go back to it.

Comment: @Tom Btw, if you load the `Userform` modeless (e.g. `Userform1.Show vbModeless` ), issue seems to disappears and activates the sheet just fine.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind after looking at the code you've provided, have you tried disconnecting from DB before you Unload the form?

Comment: @L42 I've tried loading the Userform `vbModeless` and it throws an error on a line where I set the `ActiveConnection`. Interestingly though. I've got two copies of the tool with different connection methods. In the other one (Where the connection method is done in a module) It works fine. The one with an issue the connection method is written as a Class. But other then that the code is pretty much the same

Comment: @Zac it is disconnected before I unload

Comment: @Tom I will get back once I can re-create this. I can't atm (it seems I have to connect to a database, do the dump and update of sheet), but I confirm that this happens to me too.

Comment: @L42 Great thank you - I'm glad it's not just me. Any idea of when you will be able to post your version of it? I'm going to remove my code as I don't think it adds anything to the question. Hopefully we will be able to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Tom Don't remove it. A little clue is better than no clue at all. As for when I will post, as soon as I can replicated it consistently.

Comment: @L42 ok have rolled back.